# Setting up a general purpose colored syntax highlighter using listings in latex

Tags: python, numbers, latex, operators, listings

I am interested in setting up a Python (but this will hopefully be extendable to other languages as well) syntax highlighter using listings in latex. Sadly I'm no latex expert and I've piece-mealed something together that come close to what I want, but still falls a bit short. (I would like to highlight Python code as the TigerJython IDE does for educational purposes).
Highlighting numbers which are not in character strings was one of the main challenges and the solution essentially prevents me from using literate or morekeywords for highlighting single symbol operators. I can give all other characters in the character table a distinct color, but I would like different colors for operators and brackets. This is the last thing I'm still missing.
I'll give a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %converting to PDF
\usepackage{listings} % for python code snippets
\usepackage{xinttools}% for expandable and non-expandable loops

% color definitions
\definecolor{Code}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{RGB}{0,51,170}
\definecolor{Keyfunctions}{RGB}{119,0,136}
\definecolor{Strings}{RGB}{204,102,0}
\definecolor{Comments}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{Numbers}{RGB}{204,51,0}
\definecolor{Operators}{RGB}{128,64,64}
\definecolor{Datatypes}{RGB}{0,128,128}
\definecolor{Brackets}{RGB}{0,51,102}

% make @ interpretable as a character
\makeatletter

% various operator characters for the after sign function
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"25}\lstum@percent
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"26}\lstum@and
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"2A}\lstum@star
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"2D}\lstum@minus
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"2D}\lstum@dot
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"3C}\lstum@lt
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"3D}\lstum@equal
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"3E}\lstum@gt
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"7B}\lstum@lbrace
\lst@SaveOutputDef{"7D}\lstum@rbrace

% some complex replacement setup to highlight numbers correctly
\newif\iffirstchar\firstchartrue
\newif\ifstartedbyadigit
\newif\ifprecededbysign
\newif\ifbracketfalse

\newcommand{\brackets}{()[]}

% this is where the preceding operators are declared
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}%
{%
  \lst@IfLastOtherOneOf{,?!=+/([ \lstum@percent \lstum@and \lstum@star \lstum@minus \lstum@lt \lstum@gt \lstum@lbrace \lstum@lbrace}
    {\global\precededbysigntrue}
    {}%
    \IsOperator
}

% replacement function for numbers
\lst@AddToHook{Output}%
{%
  \ifprecededbysign
      \ifstartedbyadigit
        \def\lst@thestyle{\color{Numbers}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \global\firstchartrue
  \global\startedbyadigitfalse
  \global\precededbysignfalse
}

\newcommand\processletter
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode
    \iffirstchar%
        \global\startedbyadigitfalse
      \fi
      \global\firstcharfalse
    \fi
}
\newcommand\processdigit
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode
      \iffirstchar
        \global\startedbyadigittrue
      \fi
      \global\firstcharfalse
  \fi
}

\newcommand\addtoletterdef[2]
{%
  \expandafter\lst@DefSaveDef
  \expandafter{%
  \expandafter`%
  \expandafter#2%
  \expandafter}%
  \csname why#2\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{\csname why#2\endcsname #1}%
}

% helper macro for operators
\newcommand\IsOperator
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{Operators}}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\IsBracket
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{Brackets}}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
deletekeywords={sum,str,int,input},             % remove keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{Keywords},
emph={len,range,True,False,input},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\color{Keyfunctions},    % Custom highlighting style
emph=[2]{int,str},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=[2]\ttb\color{Datatypes},    % Custom highlighting style
%emph=[3]{(,),[,]},          % Custom highlighting
%emphstyle=[3]\color{Brackets},    % Custom highlighting style
emph=[4]{sum},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=[4]\color{black},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{Strings},
commentstyle=\ttb\color{Comments},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false ,          % 
upquote = true,                   % quotes are straight dashes
showtabs=true,
tab=\rightarrowfill ,       
  alsoletter=0123456789.,
  SelectCharTable=%
      \xintApplyInline{\addtoletterdef\processdigit}{0123456789.}%
      \xintApplyInline{\addtoletterdef\processletter}
      {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}%
}
}

% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
i = 5+a #no symbol highlighting in comments )=?+ etc
hex_num = 0xad344
dec_num = 5.5
word = str(4) # number 4 
other_dot = c.call()
my_str='4+=5*(5+5)'
\end{python}


\end{document}
```

I believe I want to use \lst@IfSubstring and \lst@token to create a if selection between IsBracket and IsOperator in the \lst@AddToHook{OutputOther} block, but I just don't understand latex and listings well enough to see how to fit everything together :(

As said, what I'm still missing is highlighting of operators and brackets in different colors. If I could highlight the '.' character like an operator when not in a number that would round everything off. And a solution shouldn't break anything of the currently working code, in particular the number highlighting.
T

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I can really answer your question, but being the original author of *TigerJython*, let me share the LaTeX setup code I usually use to highlight Python code for my TigerJython scripts, nonetheless.

Although I tried to stick to the standard colours in the TigerJython IDE as good as possible, I also tweaked some parts of it a little to make sure it still prints well in b/w.

```latex
\RequirePackage[procnames]{listings}
%%
%%  Define some colours trying to mimic TigerJython. 
%%
\definecolor{keywordclr}{rgb}{0, 0.2, 0.667}      
\definecolor{fnctionclr}{rgb}{0.467, 0, 0.533}
\definecolor{builtinclr}{rgb}{0.467, 0, 0.533}
\definecolor{symbolsclr}{rgb}{0.5, 0.25, 0.25}   
\definecolor{commentclr}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}       
\definecolor{stringsclr}{rgb}{0.8, 0.4, 0}     
\definecolor{numbersclr}{rgb}{0.8, 0.2, 0}
\definecolor{bckgrndclr}{rgb}{0.91, 0.95, 0.95}
%%
%%  Define a new language 'Jython'. We also want strings over multiple lines 
%%  to be formatted as strings and not as comments.
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{Jython}%
  { morekeywords={None,and,as,assert,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,%
      else,except,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,nonlocal,%
      not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while,with,yield,repeat},%
    moreprocnamekeys={class,def},%
    %%  We use 'classoffset=1' to add built in functions (__builtins__)
    classoffset=1,%
    morekeywords={Exception,False,True,abs,all,any,ascii,bin,bool,bytearray,%
      bytes,callable,chr,classmethod,compile,complex,copyright,delattr,dict,%
      dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,exec,exit,float,format,frozenset,getattr,%
      globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,%
      len,license,list,locals,map,max,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,%
      property,quit,range,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,%
      staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,vars,zip,inputInt,inputFloat,%
      inputString,msgDlg,askYesNo,enum,clrScr,head,tail,indices,self},%
    classoffset=0,%
    sensitive=true,%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    morestring=[b]{'''},%
    morestring=[b]{"""}%
  }
%%
%%  Set 'Jython' as default language and set all the colors and styles.
%%
\lstset{language=Jython,% 
  extendedchars=true,%
  belowskip=0pt,%
  framexleftmargin=2pt,%
  framexrightmargin=2pt,%
  numbers=none,%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,%
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,%
  keywordstyle=\color{keywordclr}\bfseries,% 
  stringstyle=\color{stringsclr},%
  commentstyle=\color{commentclr}\itshape,%
  procnamestyle=\color{fnctionclr},%
  tabsize=4,%
  classoffset=1,%
  keywordstyle=\color{builtinclr},%
  classoffset=0,
  backgroundcolor=\color{bckgrndclr}%
}
```